# Make field required on condition

Tags: validation, required-field

We have 2 fields: One is a picklist (Final Status), and another is a multi-picklist (Condition for relisting). 
We want to make Condition for relisting required based on the value of Final Status.

Comment: If you are asking for suggestion, You can do this with either validation rule or trigger.

Comment: can you please provide any example for the same with the help of validation rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the  rule like this...

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(PICKLISTFIELD__c,'Yes'), ISBLANK(MULTIPICKLISTFIELD__c))
```

Hope this might helps...